# How to convert a Schema-less json column into dictionary , json or another datafram in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I am working with PysPark and I'm quite new in this field ,
I have a DataFrame (df) with 15 columns (e.g. col1 , col2 , col3 , ...col15) and a corresponding LOG Table for tracking changes inside T  ,the LOG TABLE (LG) has 3 Columns ( ID , EntityID, Changes) and the "changes" column holds changes .For example I may have string inside LG like this :

```
+----+---+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
|ID  | EntityID |        Changes                                             |
+----+---+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
|1   |2         |{"Col1" :val1 ; "Col2":val2 ; "Col12" : val12}              |
|2   |3         |{"Col7" :val7 ; "Col12":val12;"Col19":val19 ;"Col15":val15} |
|3   |3         |{"Col1" :val1 ; col2:val2; ....            ;"Col15":val15}  |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

NOW I want to do some aggregations on what I have inside the "Changes" 
e.g sum(Col5) , avg(Col 10) groupBy (EntityID) and ....
I don't know "what" to do and "how" to do it, Cast "changes" to Dict or json or even a dataframe ?? and how to do it ? I read about from json , explode and .. but the problem is my column is not a well-formed json I think.
It would be appreciated if anyone can suggest me a solution to enable me to do aggregations upon some keys and values inside the string.

Answer (score 0):

Here I found an approach to do that.
First of all, Json was needed to be checked (I had sth like this {"col1":10, "col2":2020-04-01 16:55:12}
so pyspark.sql.functions.from_json could not map JSON string to desirable Schema.
changing Col2 to "2020-04-01 16:55:12" solved it.

```
#F is  pyspark.sql.functions
#schm in my json Schema sth like  
schm = StructType([
StructField("col1", LongType(), True),
StructField("col2", StringType(), True)])      
df.select(F.from_json(F.col("changes"),
schm
).alias("jsn")).select( 
"jsn.Col1","jsn.Col2").show()
```